# Populating a map of structs using rand.Seed() inserts only the last object

Tags: go

I have the code below, its purpose is simply to create a map of `ComicBook` struct objects and call a function that copies the map and then prints it. When I remove the `rand.Seed()` line in `SetId()` everything works (except for the id's which are constant for each run, as expected), otherwise it adds only the **last** element to the map. Why does this happen?

`comicBook.go`

```
package src

import (
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ComicBook struct {
    id        int
    name      string
    publisher string
    sold      bool
}

type Book interface {
    GetId() int
    SetId() int
    GetName() string
    GetPublisher() string
    GetIsSold() bool
    New(name string, author string) ComicBook
}

func (book ComicBook) SetId()  int{
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
        id := rand.Intn(100)
        book.id = id
    return id
}

func (book ComicBook) New(name string, author string) ComicBook {
    id := book.SetId()
    b := ComicBook{id, name, author, false}
    return b
}

func (book ComicBook) GetId() int{
    return book.id
}

func (book ComicBook) GetName() string{
    return book.name
}

func (book ComicBook) GetPublisher() string{
    return book.publisher
}

func (book ComicBook) GetIsSold() bool{
    return book.sold
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "awesomeProject1/src"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    ComicBook src.ComicBook
)

func copyMap(m map[int]src.ComicBook) map[int]src.ComicBook {
    newMap := make(map[int]src.ComicBook)
    for k, v := range m {
        newMap[k] = v
    }
    return newMap
}

func main()  {
    b := src.ComicBook{}.New("A", "B")
    bTwo := src.ComicBook{}.New("The Dark Knight Returns", "DC Comics")
    bThree := src.ComicBook{}.New("Watchmen", "DC Comics")
    m := map[int]src.ComicBook{
        b.GetId():    b,
        bTwo.GetId(): bTwo,
        bThree.GetId(): bThree,
    }
    newMap := copyMap(m)
    for k, v := range newMap {
        fmt.Println("Id: ", k, ", Name: ", v.GetName(), ", Publisher: ", v.GetPublisher(), ", Sold: ", v.GetIsSold())
    }
}
```

**Output:**

`Id:  91 , Name:  Watchmen , Publisher:  DC Comics , Sold:  false`

Comment: *"Why does this happen?"* -- Because the seed value you think is unique isn't and passing the same seed will produce the same result from math/rand, which means same id, and keys in a map need to be unique, so if you pass in 3 of the same ids as the key you'll get one record.

Comment: @mkopriva got it. So it should be called only once, from ```main``` for example. Thanks

Comment: That should "fix" it for some runs but not all. I don't think `rand.Intn` guarantees never to return the same value twice. I mean randomness and uniqueness aren't one and the same thing.

Comment: Note also that the reason you're getting the same value for 3 calls of `time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()` is *most probably* because you're executing the code in some "sandbox" environment, like the playground, or something else that distorts the normal behavior of the time package. On my machine, when I execute time.Now/rand.Seed/rand.Intn 3 time in succession, the output is 3 different (not every time it's run) integers. When I execute the same code on the playground for example, the 3 integers are all the same every time it's run.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8x75udC -- notice the second run, there are two 61s, that would result in only two books in your map. Basically your algo to generate unique ids for the books is very much flawed, but maybe you already knew that. And here's what the code produces in an "unnatural" environment: https://play.golang.org/p/gT8TCpHLCoe

Comment: @mkopriva no, I'm executing it in Goland and the output is perfectly fine now, with the change I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You use unsafe method for generate id. i make test your code:

https://play.golang.org/p/S0_CWMqNH2-

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
id := rand.Intn(100)
fmt.Println(id)
```

this unsave. You can think, identical keys can be 1/100
BUT. you do not read that the time between these operations may be too short and, as a result, the key itself is identical
my test:

```
1257894000000000000
0
1257894000000000000
0
1257894000000000000
0
```

Use single variable for save your seed, like this:
(i use global var, but you can add seed var in ComicBook struct)

```
import (
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)
var seed int
```

...

```
func (book *ComicBook) SetId()  int{
    seed += 1
    rand.Seed(int64(seed))
    id := rand.Intn(100)
```

and test:

```
1
81
2
86
3
8
```

on your code, any map element have 0 key and rewrite each other, but now:

```
map[8:{8   false} 81:{81   false} 86:{86   false}]
map[8:{8   false} 81:{81   false} 86:{86   false}]
Id:  86 , Name:   , Publisher:   , Sold:  false
Id:  8 , Name:   , Publisher:   , Sold:  false
Id:  81 , Name:   , Publisher:   , Sold:  false
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Z9_tFNdlBqp

and, if use variable for id, your no needed use rand:

```
func (book *ComicBook) SetId()  int{
    seed += 1
    book.id = seed
    fmt.Println(book.id)
    return seed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must `rand.Seed()` only once (for example in `main` or `init` function).

Secondly, `rand.Intn()` may return same value twice (because it is random, not unique), which means that previous recording of map will be overwriting.

Solution to your problem will be change function, that returns random numbers, to function, that returns some identifier (like UUID).